# Calculate large numbers of type string in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c

Say that we have two numbers of type string. Is there any possible method to add, subtract, multiply, divide and even modulus the numbers inside the string without converting them back to number format. If yes, how?

Comment: What do you want to accomplish?

Comment: @HotLicks 
Be able to do math operation within a string.

Comment: @Hot Licks arbitrary-precision arithmetic without using any existing library provided

Comment: NSDecimalNumber will go out to 38 decimal places.  Do you need more?

Comment: (In any event, it would be unwise to use NSString for this.  Better to use NSData, or just an array of byte/int/whatever.)

Comment: @Hot Licks Thanks mate, but I am currently working on my assignment, it specifies NSString for the type. The number will go up to 70 digits. So I am just not sure how to get this done.

Comment: Well then, I guess you just have to sit down and write code.  Bummer.

Answer (score 0):

No, there's nothing built in. You'll have to write your own or convert to/from numbers (assuming the number types have enough storage).

Comment: What if the number is too big for integer type? How can I do those math operation within a string? Thanks